# can you draw excel chart from subset of pivot table columns

Tags: pivot-table, excel-2010

Need a vertical bar chart based on only some columns of pivot table even that table contains other columns too. But vertical bar chart should be based on only few columns.

Tried inserting charts, but that pivot chart is based on all columns in pivot table.